# Как осуществить перебор в цикле экземпляров класса с предоставлением данных экземпляра

Tags: java, классы, циклы

Как осуществить перебор в цикле экземпляров класса с предоставлением данных экземпляра. Т.е имеются экземпляры класса MeasurePoint MP1-MP3 которые содержат данные о себе.
Как в одном цикле оперировать данными разных экземпляров? Чтобы при первом прохождении по циклу выдавать данные MP1 класса, по j++ MP2 ...etc

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // write your code here

            MeasurePoint MP1 = new MeasurePoint();
            MeasurePoint MP2 = new MeasurePoint();
            MeasurePoint MP3 = new MeasurePoint();

            MP1.setValue(100.45);//double
            MP2.setValue(200.54);
            MP3.setValue(300.05);

            MP1.setDestinationName("some name1");//string
            MP2.setDestinationName("some name2");
            MP3.setDestinationName("some name3");

            MP1.setValueMin(101);//int
            MP2.setValueMin(102);
            MP3.setValueMin(103);

            ArrayList<MeasurePoint> listMP = new ArrayList<>();
            listMP.add(MP1);
            listMP.add(MP2);
            listMP.add(MP3);

            System.out.println(listMP.size()); //3

            for (int j = 0; j < listMP.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println(MP1.getDestinationName());
                System.out.println(MP1.getValue());
                System.out.println(MP1.getValueMin());
            }
        }
    }


  public class MeasurePoint {

        private String destinationName;
        private String destinationColor;

        private String valueColor;
        private double value;
        private int valueMin;
        private int getValueMax;


        public String getDestinationName() {
            return destinationName;
        }

        public void setDestinationName(String destinationName) {
            this.destinationName = destinationName;
        }

        public String getDestinationColor() {
            return destinationColor;
        }

        public void setDestinationColor(String destinationColor) {
            this.destinationColor = destinationColor;
        }

        public String getValueColor() {
            return valueColor;
        }

        public void setValueColor(String valueColor) {
            this.valueColor = valueColor;
        }

        public double getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(double value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValueMin() {
            return valueMin;
        }

        public void setValueMin(int valueMin) {
            this.valueMin = valueMin;
        }

        public int getGetValueMax() {
            return getValueMax;
        }

        public void setGetValueMax(int getValueMax) {
            this.getValueMax = getValueMax;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Как то так: `System.out.println(listMP.get(j).getDestinationName());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        for (MeasurePoint mp: listMP) {
            System.out.println(mp.getDestinationName());
            System.out.println(mp.getValue());
            System.out.println(mp.getValueMin());
        }
```